# How to keep WGPU RenderPipeline alive after storing it in a void pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, webgpu

I am trying to store a wgpu::RenderPipeline as a void pointer

`pipeline.rendering_data (this is void*) = wgpuDeviceCreateRenderPipeline(device, &pipeline_desc);`

However, when I do this I get this error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `0`,
  right: `1`: RenderPipeline[1] is no longer alive', /root/.cargo/git/checkouts/wgpu-53e70f8674b08dd4/011a4e2/wgpu-core/src/hub.rs:348:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./jovial_test
```